# Give UI objects an id after creating a dynamic UI using merge

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to adapt my UI to follow the guide here http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html as it seems perfect for what I'm after

I currently have a TableView with any number of table rows in (which has a weight of 3) that contains 3 image buttons (each with a layout weight of 1). The way the app works is that when I send a query for the UI to the server, I get back a list of images for what the user can and cannot use, so there may be any number of images that need to be displayed, so rather than have a static UI, this merge system looks perfect as I can just keep adding rows

My issue though is this. Each table row has 3 buttons and each button needs an id. Is there a way that I can allocate an id to an image button after the Inflater has created the row?

Comment: do not use TableView for more rows than can be shown on screen ... use some kind of AdapterView(fx. ListView)

Comment: Ok, but for using merge with buttons in it, can the id be set once the inflater has inflated them?